# Loop Text to Columns macro in Excel for multiple selected columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to perform the "Text to Columns" feature on several columns of data in Excel. How can I modify the VBA script of my macro to do this? Right now, I can only select one column for my macro, but I'd like to select multiple columns, and have this loop through somehow.

Also, is there any way to write script that clicks "okay" for me, when it asks if I can overwrite the data in the next column?

```
Sub text2col()
'
' text2col Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Option+Cmd+k
'
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range(ActiveCell.Address), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
        :="-", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1))
End Sub
```

Comment: You could wrap a `For Each col In Selection ... Next` around this, but its behaviour could be unpredictable as the `TextToColumns` function inserts additional columns. `DisplayAlerts = False` will stop Excel asking you the questions, but be sure to turn it back on again afterwards!

Comment: Text-to-Columns can only perform its split on a single column. If you have data in the next column, it will overwrite it. Yes, you can select more than a single column but you would have to a) overwrite the next column or b) predetermine the max number of elements to be split and insert that many blank columns. The next loop would have to adjust to the inserted columns.

Answer (score 0):

- change 1 to the column number of the 1st column you need to change
- change 10 to the column number of the last column you need to change
- columns are numbered from the left (A) starting with 1

Make sure you pay attention to [Mark Wickett](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29761903/loop-text-to-columns-macro-in-excel-for-multiple-selected-columns#comment47655829_29761903)'s warning in his comment.

```
Sub text2col()
'
' text2col Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Option+Cmd+k
'
Dim Col as Integer

  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  For Col = 1 to 10 
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range(ActiveCell.Address), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
    :="-", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1))
  Next
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: should that be `Selection.Columns( Col ).TextToColumns`...? And wouldn't the execution of this on the first column overwrite the others with the destination being the current cell?